# How does FOG Project PXE supply a computer name and join to the domain?

Tags: windows-7, pxe, sysprep, unattended, fog

**Without** sysprepping (just uploading then deploying) I can get FOG to seamlessly join an imaged computer to a domain, and FOG will also supply a computer name I specify in the management console.  My confusion (and question) comes when you supply a answer file to sysprep.  If a computer name is supplied and or is blank e.g.

```
<ComputerName></ComputerName>
```

(or ComputerName tag omitted from the unattend.xml)
will FOG correctly supply a computer name without windows generating a random name or prompting? How does FOG join a domain if a domain join is not already specified in the answer file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out from the documentation [here](http://wiki.rscwmsystems.org.uk/images/4/47/Using_Fog.pdf):

Hostname Changer

On Windows startup, the Fog Client service compares the computer name with the information 
stored in the Fog database. If the names are different, it will automatically rename and reboot the 
computer.
This service can be used in conjunction with automated Windows setup after imaging. If the 
computer name is left blank in the unattended setup answer file, Windows 7 will assign a random 
name to the computer. The correct name will be assigned by the Fog hostname changer.